# Compiler Error expression was too complex to be resolved

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error:

> Expression was too complex to be resolved in reasonable time

Please help me out. What should I do? I am using the same line in the previous view controller and it's working perfectly.

```
let url = URL(string: self.con+"loc?email="+email+"&lat="+lati+"&log="+logi!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this error is that Xcode gets confused when you use too many + signs. Always try to use the String Interpolation:

```
let paramsStr = "loc?email=\(email)&lat=\(lati)&log=\(logi)"
```

Also a good read about this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931329/3403364

Answer (score 0):

Break it down to smaller expressions. Swift compiler is too dumb to understand your expression ))

Like this:

`let paramsStr = "loc?email=" + email + "&lat=" + lati + "&log=" + logi
 let url = URL(string: self.con + paramsStr)`