# Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time- Appending Strings

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Im getting this error at

```
let encoded = akey.aesEncrypt(key: "hello", iv: "abc");

---> var data = "val1="+data1+"&val2="+data2+"&val3="+data3
```

What I'm I doing wrong ?

Please advice

Comment: The marked question does not explain how to solve the string concatenation issue ...Is there a replacement for the '+' operator ?

Comment: Did you try string *interpolation* (as suggested in an answer to the referenced question)?

Comment: @MartinR For any one who might come across this question.This is a compiler issue with swift to do with '+' operator overloading.This can be solved by string interpolation e.g.:`var data="data1=\(value1)&data2=\(value2)&data3=\(value3)"`

Comment: That is exactly what this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39514629/1187415 suggests: *"concatenating strings with interpolation ... is much better than ..."* – why do you think that it is not a duplicate or should be reopened?

Comment: @MartinR That is a lengthy explanation and does not directly show an example to solve this ie:String Interpolation.I think an example would be helpful for beginners like me.